# How to obtain the cumulative distribution function

Tags: r, distribution, probability-density

I have a random variable which I can obtain the density of

```
density(r)->pdf
```

how can I obtain the cumulative distribution function (cdf) from this pdf with R?

I tried

```
approxfun(pdf$x,pdf$y,yleft=0,yright=0)->f
cdf<-integrate(f,-Inf,2)
```

but when I plot cdf I only obtain

1.000396 with absolute error < 7.9e-05

Comment: I think you want `ecdf`.  See `?ecdf`

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30858/how-to-calculate-cumulative-distribution-in-r

Comment: This question should not be marked as duplicate as it is referring to getting the CDF of a density object, which is different from the ecdf related answers linked ot.

Comment: See answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/553271/193123

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `logspline` package of `R` for creating and visualising smooth nonparametric cumulative distribution functions (and other related quantities) as follows.

```
library(logspline) # load the package
x <- rnorm(500) # generate some data
x.lsp <- logspline(x) # create the logspline object
plot(x.lsp, what="p") # plot the distribution function
plot(x.lsp, what="d") # plot the density function
```